# Set a description field to be required if checkbox is checked "Yes" in an Access Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my form I have a "Decline/Accept Contract" check box field and if this field is checked then I need the next field (long text) "Decline Reason" to be required. This field is only required is "Yes" is selected. I have tried variations of the following in the Before/AfterUpdate properties in both fields but nothing seems to work.

`If Me.Decline_Accept_Contract = "Yes" And IsNull(Me.Decline_Reason) Then
MsgBox "Decline reason is required."
Cancel = True
Me.Decline_Reason.SetFocus
End If`

I also tried setting a validation rule in the table properties
`[Decline/Accept Reason]="Yes"` but this just gave me the validation message regardless of which field was clicked. It was not actually validating on the "yes" in the Decline/Accept Reason.

Any help provided is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbox should be *Null* when empty, thus:

```
If Me!Decline_Accept_Contract.Value = True And IsNull(Me!Decline_Reason.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Decline reason is required."
    Cancel = True
    Me!Decline_Reason.SetFocus
End If
```

Or you can use *Nz*:

```
If Me!Decline_Accept_Contract.Value = True And Nz(Me!Decline_Reason.Value) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Decline reason is required."
    Cancel = True
    Me!Decline_Reason.SetFocus
End If
```

Comment: @ Gustav, thanks for the help! It worked as did my table property validation rule solution

Answer (score 0):

The Checkbox will have a default value of True or False, not string value of "Yes". Also, the textbox will be an empty string if text has been entered and deleted. best to check for both cases like this...

```
If Me.Decline_Accept_Contract And len(trim(Me.Decline_Reason.Value & vbnullstring))=0 Then
    MsgBox "Decline reason is required."
    Cancel = True
    Me.Decline_Reason.SetFocus
End If
```

Comment: @ Lord Peter, thanks for pointing out true/false, I realized that when I got the following to work as a validation rule in the table properties and validates deleted text.  I put this code in OnClick, is that correct? It appears to be working but still allows me to delete text without validating again so I can enter text to fulfill the validation but can then delete.                                                                                                  ([Decline Reason] Is Null And [Decline/Accept Contract]=False) Or ([Decline Reason] Is Not Null And [Decline/Accept Contract]=True)

Comment: @TechEng You would typically use code like this in the BeforeUpdate event of a bound Form to stop the record being saved (Cancel=True) unless the conditions are met...